# Android Emulator could not allocate 1.0gb of memory for the current AVD configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am a beginner in app development. I just started a project but when I try to run the app in android emulator it shows this error;

**

> Android Emulator could not allocate 1.0 GB of memory for the current
>   AVD configuration. Consider adjusting the RAM size of your AVD in the
>   AVD manager. Error Detail: QEMU 'pc.ram'

**

I have a core 2 quad pc with 4gb ram and x86 system. I am very new to programming so somebody please give detailed instructions on how to solve this error and the run the app on emulator. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is configuration.
Confirm that "x86_64" of "Marshmallow" is selected, and click "Next".
that's all

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First find the ADV [image: Second Start]

second start the ADV. Emulator started and worked fine. But don't know what actually happened behind the scene